# Crossrider Messaging API is not supported by IE

Tags: internet-explorer, crossrider

I got this error when STAGING my extension in IE10, I though crossrider has APIs that internet explorer

The Error:
[Sun Aug 11 2013 13:08:32] Extension staging

Need help in solving this from any crossrider employee out there or anyone in this matter

Comment: The error you quoted looks like a standard console message. Please can you clarify what the actual error is? Also, if you can provide the extension id I'd be happy to take a look for you. [Disclaimer] I am a Crossrider employee

Comment: [Sun Aug 11 2013 13:22:51] Extension staging <Warning: Object doesn't support this property or method Function-name: appAPI.message.addListener User callback>

Comment: In general, this error message indicates that there is an error in your [appAPI.message.addListener](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.message-method-addListener) callback function code. If you supply the code or the extension id, I am happy to help you debug the code. [Disclaimer] I am a Crossrider employee